# Trying to parse JSON into data contract Please do not simply suggest Newtonsoft as it does not work either

Tags: json, datacontract

*Please provide feedback as to what I am doing wrong
Please do not recommend NewtonSoft JSON as it does not work either *

```
 [DataContract]
       public class WeatherContract
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "version")]
        public string version { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "weather")]
        public string weather { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "temp_f")]
        public string temp_f { get; set; }
    }

    string URI = 

  "http://api.wunderground.com/api/969c30d9979df192/conditions/q/OR/Roseburg.json";

    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x- 
   www-form-urlencoded";

     string stringResult = wc.DownloadString(URI);
     ProgLog.Log(stringResult, PROCNAME, MODNAME);

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(stringResult));

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new 
    DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(WeatherContract));
    WeatherContract weather = (WeatherContract)ser.ReadObject(ms);
```

*Below the version, weather, and temp_f are blank*
     ProgLog.Log("Version : " + weather.version + " : " + "weather : " + weather.weather + " / " + weather.temp_f, PROCNAME, MODNAME);

*Here is the raw JSON from Weather Underground*

```
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "conditions": 1
  }
    }
  , "current_observation": {
        "image": {
        "url":"http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
        "title":"Weather Underground",
        "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
        },
        "display_location": {
        "full":"Roseburg, OR",
        "city":"Roseburg",
        "state":"OR",
        "state_name":"Oregon",
        "country":"US",
        "country_iso3166":"US",
        "zip":"97470",
        "magic":"1",
        "wmo":"99999",
        "latitude":"43.22000122",
        "longitude":"-123.33999634",
        "elevation":"146.9"
        },
        "observation_location": {
        "full":"North Bend, Oregon",
        "city":"North Bend",
        "state":"Oregon",
        "country":"US",
        "country_iso3166":"US",
        "latitude":"43.23",
        "longitude":"-123.35",
        "elevation":"524 ft"
        },
        "estimated": {
        },
        "station_id":"MKRBG",
        "observation_time":"Last Updated on May 9, 12:10 PM PDT",
        "observation_time_rfc822":"Wed, 09 May 2018 12:10:30 -0700",
        "observation_epoch":"1525893030",
        "local_time_rfc822":"Wed, 09 May 2018 12:13:46 -0700",
        "local_epoch":"1525893226",
        "local_tz_short":"PDT",
        "local_tz_long":"America/Los_Angeles",
        "local_tz_offset":"-0700",
        "weather":"Mostly Cloudy",
        "temperature_string":"64.0 F (17.8 C)",
        "temp_f":64.0,
        "temp_c":17.8,
        "relative_humidity":"48%",
        "wind_string":"From the SW at 3.0 MPH",
        "wind_dir":"SW",
        "wind_degrees":220,
        "wind_mph":3.0,
        "wind_gust_mph":0,
        "wind_kph":4.8,
        "wind_gust_kph":0,
        "pressure_mb":"1018",
        "pressure_in":"30.06",
        "pressure_trend":"-",
        "dewpoint_string":"45 F (7 C)",
        "dewpoint_f":45,
        "dewpoint_c":7,
        "heat_index_string":"NA",
        "heat_index_f":"NA",
        "heat_index_c":"NA",
        "windchill_string":"NA",
        "windchill_f":"NA",
        "windchill_c":"NA",
        "feelslike_string":"64.0 F (17.8 C)",
        "feelslike_f":"64.0",
        "feelslike_c":"17.8",
        "visibility_mi":"10.0",
        "visibility_km":"16.1",
        "solarradiation":"--",
        "UV":"4","precip_1hr_string":"-999.00 in ( 0 mm)",
        "precip_1hr_in":"-999.00",
        "precip_1hr_metric":" 0",
        "precip_today_string":"0.03 in (1 mm)",
        "precip_today_in":"0.03",
        "precip_today_metric":"1",
        "icon":"mostlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/mostlycloudy.gif",
        "forecast_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/US/OR/Roseburg.html",
        "history_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=MKRBG",
        "ob_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=43.230000,-123.349998",
        "nowcast":""
    }
}
```

Comment: So you only care about the fields weather, temp_f and version?

Comment: Eventually I'll care about more fields but I'm starting there.

Comment: Just read that DataContractSerilizer (ships with VSTUD) does not return parsing or mal-formed JSON errors. In fact, there are no errors to trap.

Comment: Maybe JSON.NET isn't so bad afterall!